# Element 'musico' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element

Tags: xml, xsd

Tengo un problema con el XSD.
Necesito realizar una enumeración para un elemento y este a su vez es un elemento compuesto. Entonces no sé como debería hacerlo.

```
**<xs:element name="musico" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="r_musico">**
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="nombreArtistico" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="tipo" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="instrumento" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="codigo" use="required" type="r_codigo" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="cd" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tipo_cd"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Enumeración:

```
<xs:simpleType name="r_musico">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="cantautor"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="duo"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="solista"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="grupo"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="banda"/>
       </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: tienes un elemento compuesto el cual dentro tiene que tener un elemento con enumeración?

Comment: Tiene que tener una restricción, que sea un enumerador

Comment: osea tienes que meter la enumeraciónqeu has puesto abajo en el bloque de arriba?

Comment: Sí, en el elemento de arriba